# How-to serialize / deserialize multiple sets with a differing type into a single file

Tags: java, serialization

I have done a bit of research on this subject, however didn't manage to find any solution on my own.

The problem is such: 
I got three seperate Set objects with differing types.

Example:

```
private static Set<Vessel> vessels = new HashSet<Vessel>();
private static Set<Seperator> vessels1 = new HashSet<Seperator>();
private static Set<Pipe> vessels2 = new HashSet<Pipe>();
```

The Vessel, Seperator and Pipe implement **Serializable** interface.

Simplified example:

```
public class Vessel implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int id;
    public Vessel(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class Seperator implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int id;
    public Seperator(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class Pipe implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int id;
    public Pipe(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I do know how to serialize these sets into seperate files. However, I struggle to find a way to serialize all three independent sets into a single file which ultimately is the objective of my query.

Ideally I am looking for an example on how-to serialize and de-serialize multiple sets with differing types into a single file.

Comment: Why don't you wrap these sets in an array and write the array to a file? When you read it back, you can read the sets back from the array.

Comment: @Vasu how would I declare such an array? The type of each set is different, wouldn't I need to specify the type when declaring the array? If so, that would not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The approach suggested by @Vasu should work for you. However this will bring additional cost of deserializing the complete linked list (of sets) when you just want to deserialize the one set. So, a complete solution to your question will be possible in persistent stores like DB, but not on file system.  I am pasting the below comment from a previos SO post on a related topic.

> **Why can't a file that contains multiple appended ObjectOutputStreams
>   be deserialized by one ObjectInputStream?**
>
> Using the default implementation of serialization, there must be a
>   one-to-one mapping between ObjectOutputStream construction and 
>   ObjectInputStream construction. ObjectOutputStream constructor writes
>   a stream header and ObjectInputStream reads this stream header. A
>   workaround is to subclass ObjectOutputStream and override 
>   writeStreamHeader(). The overriding writeStreamHeader() should call
>   the super writeStreamHeader method if it is the first write to the
>   file and it should call ObjectOutputStream.reset() if it is appending
>   to a pre-existing ObjectOutputStream within the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you put individual Set objects into file, then you need to remember the order while reading them back from file. So it would be better to put those 3 sets into a class and write that class to avoid that problem. like

```
class SetValues implements Serializable {

    private static Set<Vessel> vessels = new HashSet<Vessel>();
    private static Set<Seperator> vessels = new HashSet<Seperator>();
    private static Set<Pipe> vessels = new HashSet<Pipe>();

    //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a LinkedList and add your objects with add. LinkedList implements Serializable, so you can write it to a file. Just make sure to add and read back your sets in the same order.

```
LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
l.add(vessel);
l.add(vessel1);
l.add(vessel2);
```